# NetLogo: How to identify disconnected nodes?

Tags: netlogo

I have a huge disconnected network. To check this I use `nw:eigenvector-centrality`. It reports false, if the graph is disconnected ([link](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#eigenvector-centrality)). Now I want to identify the disconnected nodes / areas, in order to remove them from the network.
Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`nw:weak-component-clusters`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#weak-component-clusters)

Alternatively, if you have one turtle you *know* is in the network (which you probably do), you can tell if any other turtle is connected by whether its reachable from that one turtle. So:

```
turtles with [ nw:distance-to known-turtle = false ]
```

will give you the agentset of turtles not reachable from `known-turtle`.